# Parsing XML from website to an Android device

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

I am starting an Android application that will parse XML from the web. I've created a few Android apps but they've never involved parsing XML and I was wondering if anyone had any tips on the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
        try {
            URL url = new URL(/*your xml url*/);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(conn.getInputStream());

            NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName(/*tag from xml file*/);
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
                NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName(/*item within the tag*/);
                Element line = (Element) title.item(0);
                phoneNumberList.add(line.getTextContent());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

In my example, my XML file looks a little like:

```
<numbers>
   <phone>
      <string name = "phonenumber1">555-555-5555</string>
   </phone>
   <phone>
      <string name = "phonenumber2">555-555-5555</string>
   </phone>
</numbers>
```

and I would replace `/*tag from xml file*/` with "phone" and `/*item within the tag*/` with "string".

Comment: This is causing me this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270372/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-when-trying-to-connect-over-wifi-using

Comment: Note that this must be done **on a background thread** or it will cause a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Answer (score 1):

I always use the w3c dom classes.  I have a static helper method that I use to parse the xml data as a string and returns to me a Document object.  Where you get the xml data can vary (web, file, etc) but eventually you load it as a string.

something like this...

```
    Document document = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder;

    try
    {
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(data));
        document = builder.parse(is);
    }
    catch (SAXException e) { }
    catch (IOException e) { }
    catch (ParserConfigurationException e) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of parsing mechanisms available, one is SAX [Here is SAX parsing example](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example), second is DOM parsing [Here is DOM Parsing example.](http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2011/07/parsing-xml-wit-dom-parser.html). From your question it is not clear what you want, but these may be good starting points.

Comment: Thanks very much guys, il give them a try hear, time to hit the books on the DOM and SAX parsing then :( lol

Answer (score 1):

There are three types of parsing I know: DOM, SAX and XMLPullParsing.

In my example here you need the URL and the parent node of the XML element.

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.something.com/something.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    NodeList nodeList1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("parent node here");
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList1.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = nodeList1.item(i);
    }
} catch(Exception e) {

}
```

Also try [this](http://androiddevelopement.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using.html).

Comment: Note that this must be done **on a background thread** or it will cause a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the DOM parser, it is not as efficient as SAX, if the XML file is not too large, as it is easier in that case.

I have made just one android App, that involved XML parsing. XML received from a SOAP web service. I used XmlPullParser. The implementation from Xml.newPullParser() had a bug where calls to nextText() did not always advance to the END_TAG as the documentation promised. There is a work around for this.