# Unable to fetch JSON as String from a REST API

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am trying to fetch JSON from a REST API as a string.

I am using `retrofit` with `scalarConverter` for that purpose. I am able to pass the URL to fetch and my retrofit instance is also created successfully but I am not getting any response from the server.
PS: there is no request on the server, so that means my request is not going out from my machine.

I am new to android, kindly help me.

**Retrofit instance creation:**

```
Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(base)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
jsonApi jsonapi=retrofit.create(jsonApi.class);
Call<String> stringcall=jsonapi.getStringResponse(speech);
```

**jsonApi interface:**

```
public interface jsonApi {
    @GET
    Call<String> getStringResponse(@Url String url);
}
```

**base**: it is the base URL

**speech**: it is a variable containing rest of the URL to be processed.

when I run, the app gets stuck here with this message being displayed in **Run Tab**:

```
W/OpenGLRenderer: Fail to change FontRenderer cache size, it already initialized
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the below line

```
Call<String> stringcall=jsonapi.getStringResponse(speech);
```

you just get a `Call` object which is a representation of the HTTP request, and just by that, the request isn't executed. You need to use this object and call the `execute` method to make a synchronous request or the `enqueue` method to make an asynchronous request.

So in case you want to make a sync request, try the below:

```
Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(base)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
jsonApi jsonapi=retrofit.create(jsonApi.class);
Call<String> stringcall=jsonapi.getStringResponse(speech);
try {
    Response<String> response = stringcall.execute();
    String result = response.body();
} catch (Exception ex) { 
    //handle exception
}
```

The documentation of `Call` interface is [here](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html), for your reference.

Comment: I tried to make a sync request by `execute()` method but the app crashed. So, i tried the `enqueue` method in which the app is not crashing but it showing nothing. @Madhu Here is the snippet:
`stringcall.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                //do something
                Log.d("here","here");
                 }
@Override
 public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {}
});`

Comment: @SyedAsnalRizvi what is the error/exception when the app crashed on using the `execute` method?

Comment: W/System.err: **android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException**
W/System.err:     at **android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)**
@Madhu Bhat

Comment: @SyedAsnalRizvi looks like its due to making the network call over UI thread. Can you try the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270372/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-when-trying-to-connect-over-wifi-using which suggests using AsyncTask for the network calls.

Comment: I got it, 
thanks for the help.
Much appreciated. @Madhu Bhat